# Can the Shader Model affect Compute Shader behaviour?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, gpu, shader, hlsl

When I run my compute shader on my PC, it works. If I run it on my Mac, it does not. Based on some debugging, I *think* the problem is that for whatever reason the Y-, Z- and W-components of an important texture are always zero, even if I force-assign an arbitrary value to them.

So: **Can the Shader Model affect Compute Shader behaviour?**

If I call SystemInfo.graphicsShaderLevel it returns this:

- On PC: 50 ("Shader Model 5.0 (DX11.0)" according to Unity)
- On Mac: 45 ("Metal / OpenGL ES 3.1 capabilities (Shader Model 3.5 + compute shaders)" according to Unity)

I've tried looking for more information on the topic but the most I could find were these:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-sm3
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3dhlsl/d3d11-graphics-reference-sm5

And I can't find any official information about what Unity refers to as "Shader Model 3.5 + compute shaders".

Answer (score 0):

Is the graphics api you use metal or opengl? Note that the version of opengl(4.1) on mac does not support compute shader.

First make sure you use metal on your mac.